# I need my image to remain after the image changes

Tags: image

I have created an app that has multiple image changes. After the original image1 is changed from a pushed button it switches to a new image2. 
if i go out of the app and then back in, the image2 is back to image1. How can i get the image2 to stay?

Is this persisting data, can someone please help me?

Comment: HTML? Mobile Phone? Windows Forms? Unix? Linux? Hmm?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a init method and load the image according to a value you save upon quitting the app. If the target is iphone you can save a value in NSUserDefaults or you can create a .plist and write to and read from it. Another option is xml, which works with many programming languages.
If you want to know more i suggest you say what language/platform you are programming in/for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am writing for the iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Then I would use this:

.h

```
int imageValue;
```

.m

```
-(void)exitingApp {

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[prefs setInteger:imageValue forKey:@"value"];

}

-(void)init {

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

imageValue = [prefs integerForKey:@"value"];

myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image%i", imageValue];

}

-(void)switchToImage1 {
//This is how you go about changing the image in the app
imageValue = 1;
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image%i", imageValue];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If "value" is just the key you make so that you can track your saved int down. You can just keep it at "value". The integer starts at 0, so you call your first image: "image0.png" then the next one: "image1.png"

I found some errors in my code, this is corrected here, replace this in your project:

```
 -(void)init {

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


imageValue = [prefs integerForKey:@"value"];

myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image%i.png", imageValue];

}

-(void)switchToImage1 {
//This is how you go about changing the image in the app
imageValue = 1;
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image%i.png", imageValue];

}
```

Everything should be working now, as long as you name your images: "image0.png" and "image1.png".